# Show json data in view in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, facebook-graph-api

I am developing facebook app in which i am fetching user's friend detail in as

```
dynamic result = client.Get("me/friends"); //it gives friend's data for id, name
```

it gives data in

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Steven", 
      "id": "57564897"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Andy", 
      "id": "8487581"
    }
}
```

Now i would like to parse this data and store it. so that i can use it my way.

I was trying to parse it using **JSON.NET** and show the data in view as

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FriendDetail>(result.data);
```

in the class :

```
public class FriendDetail
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        public FriendDetail(string i, string n)
        {
            id = i;
            name = n;
        }
    }
```

Now so that i can pass the view as "`return View(model)`"

But its giving me error: `The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FBApp.Models.FBFriendDetail>(string)' has some invalid arguments`

Why this error is occurring ?

Please help me to parse this json data.

Also is there any better way to **parse and Store** json data and also then show in view ?

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to deserialize a list of `FriendDetail` objects into a single `FriendDetail` object.  Try the following:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(result.ToString());
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FriendDetail>>(jObject["data"].ToString());
```

**EDIT**

This is how I tested it:

```
var result = 
    @"{
        ""data"": [
        {
            ""name"": ""Steven"", 
            ""id"": ""57564897""
        }, 
        {
            ""name"": ""Andy"", 
            ""id"": ""8487581""
        }]
    }";

var jObject = JObject.Parse(result.ToString());
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FriendDetail>>(jObject["data"].ToString());
```

Comment: giving error The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: I have just pasted the code that I used to test it.  Does that not work on your machine?  Note that I had to add a closing brace `]` to the end of your JSON array (it was missing in your example).  Could that be the issue?

Comment: I also see that `result` is dynamic so I'm not sure what type it is.  Try calling `.ToString()` or it before passing it to `JObject`.  I have updated my answer.